# IF clause construction over awk command in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, redhat

I need to run a **ls -l** command and extract the modification date of files. Then, compare with the actual date, and, if not equal (ie. the file hadn´t been updated on current day), extract their filename to another file. Here what I got so far:

```
DATA1=`date | awk '{print $2}'`
DATA2=`date | awk '{print $3}'`
ls -l <file_path> | awk '{  if ( $DATA1 != $6 && $DATA2 -ne $7 ); then echo "Founded" }' | wc -l
```

I´ve extracted the month and the day from current date, compared to month and day from list command, and I'm doing a word count to check the number of files that hadn´t been updated, before add the redirecting command for their filenames to a new file.

The problem is that the if clause isn´t processing the way it should.

**Notes:**

- $6 is the Month, so it´s a string
- $7 is the day of month, so it´s a numerical char
- I´m using Red Hat 5.8 bash

Comment: Parsing `ls` is quite risky. Better loop through the files with something like `for file in *` and then use `stat` to get the information about the modified time.

Comment: You have a couple of problems here. You're failing to pass shell variables to awk correctly (use `-v awk_var="$shell_var"`). Also, I'm a little concerned about the `;` after your `if` (and the `then` is invalid syntax). Looks like you're mixing up shell and awk...

Comment: `find pattern -type f -mtime +1` will find files where the modification time is older than a day.

Comment: Thank you very much, folks. I decided to use `find` as @Kenster mentioned above. But it was nice to know about `stat` command and  those particularities about awk variables.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, this will give you all files more than 24 hours old:

```
find PATTERN -type f -mtime +1
```

This will get you anything older than midnight local time if you'd prefer that to a full day of age:

```
find PATTERN -type f -mmin +$(($(date +"%H*60+%M")))
```